# Apache PDFBox PDJpeg Inflated Image

Tags: java, pdf, pdfbox

Why does the JPEG image inflate when it is added to a PDF using Apache PDFBox?

The image size is bigger. I search but found nothing to help me.

I am using BufferedImage.  How can I fix it so that the image is same size once I added to the PDF?

Here's my code:

```
PDPage page = null;
PDXObjectImage image = null;
doc = new PDDocument();
page = new PDPage();
doc.addPage(page);
PDPageContentStream content = new PDPageContentStream(doc, page);
BufferedImage bImg = null;
bImg = ImageIO.read(new File("picture.jpg"));
image = new PDJpeg(doc, bImg);
content.drawImage(image, 100, 500);
content.close();
doc.save("test.pdf");
```

Comment: "The same size" ... as what? Does this JPEG contain meta-information on its *actual* size? (PDFs use "real world" measurement units, and 'a pixel' is *not* a real world measurement unit.)

Comment: So, let's say that an image is 125px x 125px. When I inserted into MS Word document the size is seems correct. but when I use PDFBox the image in the PDF is much bigger. So what can I do to get the size of the image to be the same as in MS Word?

Comment: How does the size in MS Word "look" correct? Is it exactly 125 x 125px when you take a screenshot (at 100% view!)? Any way, most likely pdfbox uses some arbitrary conversion from pixels to its internal units. Try explicitly setting the image size as in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25358147/write-higher-resolution-dpi-images-to-pdf

Comment: I printed out both MS Word document and PDF document. Put them together and the image on PDF is bigger then MS Word.  I also tried drawXObject, not luck.

Comment: Unrelated hint: use PDJpeg(PDDocument doc, InputStream is) to get better quality, because this avoids the JPG being decoded and encoded again. JPG is a lossy format!

Comment: I also tried PDJpeg(PDDocument doc, InputStream is) and got Out of Memory when I try to open the PDF.

Comment: Simply use 'drawXObject' instead of 'drawImage'. This method allows you to explicitly select the height and width.

Comment: If you got the "out of memory" error, make sure that the stream passed was indeed a JPG and not a PNG.